# ExtJs4 Change Field color on Statuscode

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, field, cell

Hello im struggling with ExtJs im Trying to change color in ExtJs grid where cell name is 'statuscode' if statuscode is 1 the cell has to change color in green! anybody an idea? Thanks

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.ArticleUpdateLog.model.ArticleUpdateLog', {
    extend: 'Shopware.data.Model',
    configure: function () {
        return { 
                controller: 'ArticleUpdateLog'
        };
    },
    fields: [
        { name : 'id', type: 'int', useNull: true },
        { name : 'importTimestamp', type: 'string' },
         { name : 'statuscode', type: 'string', useNull: true },
        { name : 'status', type: 'string', useNull: true }

    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each column of a grid has a renderer config `render: function(value, meta, record)`. So you can check with `record.get('status')` the current value and add a css style to the given cell.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer

Also look at the meta paramenter which grants access to style the specific cell you want.